# Android app crashes when running the video solution

Tags: android

The video solution for the app works as expected up until API 30. When I start a video in my android application, I receive an error that says qemu-system-x86-64.exe has stopped working. I have found other issues on SO regarding this file, but I didn't manage to replicate their problem on previous API-versions, so it doesn't look like it applies to this problem, but API 30 specifically. Anyone here had a similar problems like this for API 30?

This is the Logcat-output when I receive the error:

```
2020-11-30 13:26:50.206 423-721/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getParameter(0xf0900470:android.goldfish.h264.decoder, ??(0x6f600011)) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0x8000101a)
2020-11-30 13:26:50.215 423-721/? E/OMXNodeInstance: setConfig(0xf0900470:android.goldfish.h264.decoder, ConfigPriority(0x6f800002)) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0x8000101a)
2020-11-30 13:26:50.216 423-721/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getConfig(0xf0900470:android.goldfish.h264.decoder, ConfigAndroidVendorExtension(0x6f100004)) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0x8000101a)
2020-11-30 13:26:50.229 423-721/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getConfig(0xf0900470:android.goldfish.h264.decoder, ??(0x7f000003)) ERROR: UnsupportedSetting(0x80001019)
```

Comment: please attach the logcat or stack trace of the crash

Comment: Thanks for feedback, logcat output is attached

Comment: are you using exoplayer ?.... if yes looks like it's an older version. Can you mention the version of the player used and if it's old can you try updating and trying it out

Comment: I am using exoplayer. I tried updating it from 2.10.3 to 2.12.0. Then I received an error related to this: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/7905
I then imported guava 27.0.1 and received the error in my console: Error inflating class com.catsi15.rexoplayer.RExoPlayerView

Answer (score 0):

Since the StackTrace or Logcat is not provided, my guess is it has to do with the new Storage Policy in API 30.

Reference :-
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage